# Add an event to Laravel Passport on approval or before token is generated

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I am fairly new to Laravel Passport and Laravel in general and I have implemented simple OAuth server using both.

The challenge right now is to perform an external API call before authentication flow is complete.

They have info (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#events) about `AccessTokenCreated` event, however, ideally I would want to make that call before the authorization code is sent (right after user's approval `ApproveAuthorizationController::approve`) and token endpoint is called.

Could anyone give me a hint about a "laravel" way to do it?

Comment: Can you please give more context? Specially what do you mean by "code is sent"? And what is the function of external call?

Comment: authorization code for token generation
external call creates a user in a totally different application

Comment: Middleware is a great way to execute a set of instructions before an HTTP request is handled by the application

Comment: How to add it to an existing package?